# 2-D Watershed example on mathworks.com

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

[The 2-D watershed example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/watershed.html) on Mathworks.com can be summarized below:

```
bw = imread('someImage.tif');

D = -bwdist(~bw);

D(~bw) = -Inf;

L = watershed(D);
```

I am not quite understand why `D(~bw) = -Inf;` is necessary here which forces pixels that don't belong to the objects to be at -Inf (originally zero).

I tried running the program without that statement, and the result is confusing. Why is it necessary to force those pixels to -Inf in order for watershed to get correct result?

As pointed out by Frederick, I used `surf` to plot the surface here,
before running `D(~bw) = -Inf;`, the result is:

[image: Imgur]

After running it, the result is:
[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Inf` enhance the contrast between the connected component and the background. Otherwise watershed is very likely to merge all the background with the single connected component to one region. Actually an `-Inf` setting will completely eliminate the background from the region of interest. Check out the influence of `-Inf` on the segmentation with your [sample image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622368/over-segmentation-of-watershed-algorithm). If you set `D(~bw) = 0;`, you will get:

[image]